# How to fetch and merge data according to groupby Mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with mysql and php and i want to get data according to "city" in array
Here is my table "merchants"

```
merchantid              localityId
1                           30                       
2                           30       
3                           31
4                           30
5                           32
```

Here is table "locality"

```
localityId               cityId           name
30                          1              abc 
31                          1              xyz
32                          2              xya
```

Here is table "city"

```
cityId                  name
1                       Chandigarh
2                       Panchkula
3                       Delhi
4                       Mumbai
```

And i want to fetch data according to "city/locality",For example i want to fetch all record of city(group by city),in other words i want like following output,how can i do this ?

```
{
    "Status": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "localityName": "Chandigarh",
            "FilterType": "filter",
            "result": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "",
                    //other info
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "",
                    //other info
                },
           "localityName": "Panchkula",
            "FilterType": "filter",
            "result": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "",
                    //other info
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "",
                    //other info
                },  
                ...And so on   
         }
```

I tried with following code but giving me list of locality/city , not giving me result
as i want,Where i am wrong ?

```
$this->db->select('l.localityId,c.name,c.cityId');
    $this->db->from('merchants m'); 
    $this->db->join('locality l', 'l.localityId=m.localityId');
    $this->db->join('city c', 'c.cityId=l.cityId');
    $this->db->group_by('l.cityId');         
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    if($query->num_rows() != 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Why not check which SQL query works for your case first (without using PHP!), and then implement that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code

```
$this->db->select('l.localityId,l.name')
->from('merchants m') 
->join('locality l', 'l.localityId=m.localityId')
->group_by('m.localityId')
->limit($limit);        
 $query = $this->db->get();
 if($query->num_rows() != 0)
     {
        return $res=$query->result_array();
     }
 else
     {
        return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT c.cityId,c.name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(l.localityId))) from locality l 
JOIN merchants m on l.localityId=m.localityId
JOIN city c on c.cityId=l.cityId
GROUP BY l.cityId;
```

Live demo here: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3b0ec/7)